# Loading large amounts of html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I load large amounts of HTML in javascript? I will show a snippet below. I want to get all the HTML into the "ALL HTML GOES HERE" space in the java. I know you can put smaller things like `<h1>Hello!</h1>` but I can't figure out how to get all of that into there with it working. Unless there is another way to do this let me know.

```js
  function validate() {
    var x = $('#in').val();

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
      $('#id').html('ignore');
    } else {
      $('#id').html('ALL HTML GOES HERE');
    }

  }
  window.onload = validate;
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:popupClose();">×</a>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `$("#")` supposed to be? `#` needs to be followed by an element ID.

Comment: Just an id. I put it with #.

Comment: You can put as much as you want in place of `'ALL HTML GOES HERE'`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you don't want to write all html inside ' ' , you could load html with ajax, so first you would create file

```
allhtml.html
```

containg your html, and there instead of your:

```
 $('#id').html..
```

you would use

```
$('#id').load('allhtml.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the HTML in a Javascript string, put it in the page's HTML, but hide it with `display: none;` style. Then you can copy it to `#id`.

```js
function validate() {
  var x = $('#in').val();

  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
    $('#id').html('ignore');
  } else {
    $('#id').html($("#allhtml").html());
  }

}
window.onload = validate;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:popupClose();">×</a>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="allhtml" style="display: none;">
  <div>
    ALL HTML GOES HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass it the entire string:

```
function validate() {
  var x = $('#in').val();
  var htmlString = '<div id="popup" class="overlay">';
  htmlString += '<div class="popup">';
  htmlString += '<a class="close" href="javascript:popupClose();">×</a>';
  htmlString += '<div class="content"></div></div></div>';

if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
  $('#id').html('ignore');
} else {
  $('#id').html(htmlString);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One option that can help:

You can put all the HTML in a separate HTML file and use JQuery's .load('anotherpage.html'....) method. Basically, you'd just call that like: $('#id).load('....');

Here's the documentation with examples
http://api.jquery.com/load/